# Where can I find the config file for Caffeine extension?

Tags: screensaver, caffeine

I would like to configure [Caffeine extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/) from its config file but I am not able to find it.

Where does the Caffeine extension store its settings?

`dpkg -L caffeine` does not show any config file:

```
orschiro@x230:~$ dpkg -L caffeine
/.
/etc
/etc/xdg
/etc/xdg/autostart
/etc/xdg/autostart/caffeine.desktop
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/caffeine-screensaver-freedesktop-helper
/usr/bin/caffeine
/usr/bin/caffeine-indicator
/usr/bin/caffeinate
/usr/bin/caffeine-screensaver
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/caffeine-2.8.3.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ewmh.py
/usr/share
/usr/share/locale
/usr/share/locale/he
/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/eo
/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/ja
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/nl
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/da
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/es
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/lt
/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/vi
/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/uk
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt
/usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/tr
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/ro
/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/de
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/it
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/xh
/usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/no
/usr/share/locale/no/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/no/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/fi
/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/bg
/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/ms
/usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/th
/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/gl
/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/sk
/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/ca
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/hu
/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/bs
/usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/cs
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/en_GB
/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/pl
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/ar
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/el
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/locale/eu
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/caffeine-indicator.mo
/usr/share/caffeine-indicator
/usr/share/caffeine-indicator/glade
/usr/share/caffeine-indicator/glade/GUI.glade
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/caffeine
/usr/share/doc/caffeine/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/caffeine/README
/usr/share/doc/caffeine/copyright
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/caffeine.png
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/caffeine.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/caffeinate.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/caffeine-indicator.1.gz
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/caffeine-cup-empty.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/caffeine-cup-full.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/caffeine.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/status
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/status/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/status/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/caffeine.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/status
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/status/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/status/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/caffeine.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/status
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/caffeine.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/status
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/status/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/status/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/caffeine.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/caffeine.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/scalable
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/scalable/caffeine-cup-empty.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/scalable/caffeine-cup-full.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/16
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/16/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/16/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/48
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/48/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/48/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/32
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/32/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/32/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/24
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/24/caffeine-cup-full.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/24/caffeine-cup-empty.png
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/caffeine-indicator.desktop
/usr/share/applications/caffeine.desktop
```

Comment: OK! But I think it's important to mention in the answer that the extension is completely distinct from the package from the repos. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, I think the extensions.gnome.org/local solution is far more elegant than installing Gnome Tweaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GNOME Tweaks` provides those settings under the `Extensions` tab.

[image]

---

Alternatively open your web browser (Firefox/Chrome) and visit https://extensions.gnome.org/local/.

You need to install an add-on/extension first suggested by the web-page if not installed already. Then you will be able to access settings of all the installed extensions.

Comment: I would like to mark your answer as the accepted one instead of my one. Can you please add it? Thank you!

Comment: Just edited that in :)

Comment: Awesome. Let's keep that way. Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of ALL files in the `caffeine` package, ask the packaging system:

```
dpkg -L caffeine
```

Comment: Did you read `man caffeine;man caffeinate;man caffeine-indicator`? Some packages don't come with a configuration file - they use their default configuration until you create a config file.

Comment: Found it! It's part of Tweak Tools. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/b5AjEef.png) screenshot. Do you want to add this as an answer which I can accept?